# Use SQL statement result as string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

so i have this statement:

```
select @sqlStmt = 'SELECT replace(replace(substring(base_object_name,1,CHARINDEX(''.'',base_object_name) - 1),''['',''''),'']'','''')
    FROM sys.synonyms
    WHERE name = ''S_LC'''
```

I am wondering if there is a way to use the result from that statement to, for example concatenate onto another string?

I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: @voo, yes this code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the sql statement and concatenate the result to another sql variable, you can do like this

```
           DECLARE @anotherString VARCHAR(10)

           EXEC sp_executeSQL
           'SELECT @output = replace(replace(substring(base_object_name,1,CHARINDEX(''.'',base_object_name) - 1),''['',''''),'']'','''')
           FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = ''S_LC''', N'@output VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT', @output= @anotherString OUTPUT;
```

Now @anotherString is ready to concatenate with any other string.

Please note that I have not compiled your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute it and not only store it in your variable, yes:

```
DECLARE @objName NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT @objName = REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                      SUBSTRING(base_object_name,1,
                          CHARINDEX('.',base_object_name) - 1),
                    '[',''),
                  ']','')
    FROM sys.synonyms
    WHERE name = 'S_LC'
```